# Prism 5.0 Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Composition and Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm.Desktop.dll mixe mscorlib References dependency

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, prism, conflict

In our team, we want build solution with all errors + warnings fixed. 
The only one remaining warning concerns this one:

> "warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of the
>   same dependent assembly"

After a Msbuild with diag log enabled, they are a couple of conflicts warnings:

> There was a conflict between "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "mscorlib,
>   Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e,
>   Retargetable=Yes". There was a conflict between "System,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and
>   "System, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes". "System,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" was
>   chosen because it was primary and "System, Version=2.0.5.0,
>   Culture=neutral,_ ... After investigating the References dependency, I
>   discovered stange dependency among Prism 5.0 packages

Here are the screen captures of 2 differents Prism packages referencing different version of MsCorLib: [https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=2D1F299DEB45D4A3!1101036&authkey=!AIVdICSFXPaY488&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=2D1F299DEB45D4A3!1101036&authkey=!AIVdICSFXPaY488&v=3&ithint=photo%2Cpng)

Thanks in advance for any help

-Vince

Comment: I've had these problems trying to build the packages in VS 2012. In VS 2013, all the warnings were gone.

Comment: Did you find a solution?